# In Craft Commerce, is it possible to make the product variant weight a required field?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce3

In Craft Commerce, is it possible to make the product variant weight a required field?

We are using weight to calculate shipping so it would be good if we could make it a required field to ensure that the store admin doesn't forget to enter it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, using the `Model::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES` Put this in your customer module or plugin.

```
        use craft\commerce\elements\Variant;
        use craft\base\Model;
       use craft\events\DefineRulesEvent;
        
        Event::on(
            Variant::class,
            Model::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES,
            function(DefineRulesEvent $event) {
                $rules = $event->rules;
                $rules[] = [['weight'], 'required'];
                $event->rules = $rules;
            }
        );
```